# force require login to show cart & store pages in whmcs 8.1

Tags: hook, whmcs, restrict

i want restrict two page for if user want to see this page, redirect to login page.

I create hook file (includes/hooks/disao.php) with this code

```
<?php
if (!defined("WHMCS"))
   die("This file cannot be accessed directly");

function hook_ForceEveryoneToLogin($vars) {

  $client = Menu::context('client');
  $validpages = array("login","dologin","clientarea","pwreset","contact","index");
  if (!$client && !in_array($vars['filename'],$validpages)) {
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit;
  }
}
add_hook("ClientAreaPage", 1, "hook_ForceEveryoneToLogin");
```

but this code not work on whmcs 8.1 and work only on whmcs 7.10.
Noice : want restrict pages : Cart and Store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hook's `$vars` array parameter has `loggedin` key to check if the current user is logged in, code updated:

```php
<?php
if (!defined("WHMCS")) {
   die("This file cannot be accessed directly");
}

function hook_ForceEveryoneToLogin($vars) {

    $validPages = ["login", "dologin", "clientarea", "pwreset", "contact", "index"];
    if (!$vars['loggedin'] && !in_array($vars['filename'],  $validPages)) {
        header("Location: login.php");
        exit();
    }
}
add_hook("ClientAreaPage", 1, "hook_ForceEveryoneToLogin");
```